# Solving hackerrank " Summing the N series" challenge

Tags: c++, math

I have come up with a code for the "Summing the N series" challenge from hackerrank.com. Here is a link to the problem:  https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/summing-the-n-series.

However, my "solution" does not seem to work for big numbers, and I have no idea why.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << fixed;
    int t;
    double input, sum, temp=pow(10,9) + 7, result;

    cin >> t;

    for (int o = 0; o < t; o++) {
        cin >> input;
        sum = input*input;
        result = fmod(sum, temp);
        cout << setprecision(0) << result << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 5773408242017850 is one of the test cases I'm failing.

Comment: I don't think `"stdafx.h"` will be available on hackerrank.

Comment: Such tasks can't be solved in dumb way, You need to think. First, try to find formula for sum depending on `n`. Also there is hint - you needn't to use `double` variables. `long long int` will be sufficient for you. When you use double type you lose some digits when working with big numbers..

Comment: Since `pow(10,9) + 7` is a constant, you should evaluate it and write it as a constant (most likely with an 'L' suffix).

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `double` instead of an integer type?

Comment: For future reference, it's better to post the challenge here, not behind a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot part of the equation.

From the challenge statement:

```
temp = (input * input) - ((input - 1) * (input - 1);
```

You are missing the latter half of the equation.

You could try:

```
   const long long pretemp = input - 1;
   const long long temp = (input * input) - (pretemp * pretemp);
   sum += temp;
```

You may need to rearrange the evaluation of the equation to reduce overflow issues (which could be the core concept of the challenge).